# How to upload images with random name rule in [codeigniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce, file-manager

I'm using TinyMCE filemanager to upload images, but it always use original name whenever it stores.

Is there anyway to set the name rule (by PHP) like:

> images_{auto_increment_number}

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter you can get the uploaded file or image name in one variable and just append that variable with another random number

```
$upload_data = $this->upload->data(); //Returns array of containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded.
$file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
$append_value = 'value';

$file_name .=  '_'.$append_value;
```

Hope this helps you out

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP **uniqid()** function which generates a unique ID based on the microtime (current time in microseconds). It will always create a unique file name without duplication problem.

$newimagename = uniqid() . "_image";

Hope this Helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```